# How can I create an action when the timer hits zero

Tags: jquery, timer

I want to implement jQuery Countdown timer in my project. recently I used the timer located at link

http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/

I used the following code

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#ms_timer').countdowntimer({
            minutes :2,
            seconds : 00,
            size : "lg"
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to do is that when the timer hits zero then I want to make an alert `"Time OVer"`

How can I implement this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/) you can use `timeup` callback like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#more_options").countdowntimer({
        minutes : 20‚
        size : "lg"‚
        tickInterval : 5‚
        timeSeparator : "-"‚
        timeUp : timeisUp // <----- Closure method name
    });

    function timeisUp() {
        // Code to be executed when timer expires.
        alert('Time is Up!');
    }
});
```

> **timeup**: This is the name of the callback function that is invoked when the countdown reaches zero. Within the function this refers to the division that holds the widget. No parameters are passed in. Provide the name to this option without quotes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i have one more question is there any option in this jquery that if I want to pause this timer without button click

Comment: According to the documentation I think, that isn't supported!